# Chrome prevents user from closing onBeforeUnload dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, dialog, onbeforeunload

A client is experiencing a very bizarre bug in Google Chrome. She just called me and it happened for a second time.

On the quote page for a CRM I return a string on the onbeforeunload if the quote is not saved yet. The dialog simply warns the user to make sure he/she saved the quote before leaving the page.

Now for the second time in 2 weeks the dialog kind of got stuck. Clicking 'Stay on this page' or 'Leave this page' both simply immediately gave the same dialog again. And as the dialog lives on top of the browser even closing the browser (or the tab) as a whole was impossible. Only solution: task manager.

Here in the office we use the same CRM (and have used it for a good few months) without any issue. Am I looking at a Google Chrome bug or a faulty Google Chrome installation?

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
            if (quoteIsDirty) {
                return 'Warning - You have made changes to the quote, but have not saved your changes yet. Are you sure you want to close this page?';
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you verified that there is no script attempting to close the window programmatically? Perhaps in a different `beforeunload` handler?

Comment: Yes I have.  Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the actual code, it is difficult to tell. But here are some ideas:

- Multiple or different events that would trigger `beforeunload`, such as `window.close` and `window.location = ...`
- A persistence function with an exponential back-off or similar mechanism that is inconsistent with dirty state
- A race condition

It certainly could be a Chrome bug, but I've learned to be reluctant to blame Chrome because it's almost always an issue with my application. :)